# What's the difference between no destructor vs. a default destructor

Tags: c++

Assuming this simple code:

```
#include <string>

class Foo
{
    public:
    std::string foo;

    //~Foo() = default;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
}
```

Does it make a difference if this line uncommented `//~Foo() = default;` ?

Comment: You would probably benefit from understanding rule of three/five/zero.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: @DavidJones its rule of 0, whether the destructor is user declared or not

Comment: In simple terms the default destructor is 'call the destructor on all the members' remembering that some types (like `int`) the destructor is 'do nothing - no clean-up required). But if you delete the destructor then there is no destructor and objects of the class cannot be destructed (using their destructor). That's a fair obscure circumstance. Maybe you're using a `class` as a sort of namespace and never creating instances - so no destructor required. Or maybe it's come Host provided object that isn't destructed by C++ code. Other cases may exist.